# wrong updation of data using collection but insertion is possible

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace function get_ware_house_branch(p_WAREHOUSE_IDS  in varchar2,
 p_PLACE_ID       in varchar2)
  return id_warehouse_list                     
 is
   l_warehouse_list id_warehouse_list := id_warehouse_list();
  str varchar2(300);

begin

  str := 'SELECT BRANCH_WAREHOUSE(w.wh_id, w.wh_name)
              FROM POD_WAREHOUSE_MASTER W
              where ( W.wh_id  IN  (' ||p_WAREHOUSE_IDS  || '))';

  execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list;

  for i in l_warehouse_list.first..l_warehouse_list.last loop 
      dbms_output.put_line(l_warehouse_list(i).wh_id || ', ' ||  l_warehouse_list(i).wh_name);


/*update pod_place_warehouse_mapping_tb 

 set wh_id = l_warehouse_list(i).wh_id 

 where place_id =  p_PLACE_ID ;*/


insert into pod_place_warehouse_mapping_tb (id,place_id ,wh_id )
    values
 (POD_UNIQUE_VAL_SEQ.NEXTVAL    ,p_PLACE_ID,l_warehouse_list(i).wh_id);

end loop;

commit;
 return l_warehouse_list;
end;
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how to update the data using the collection as insertion is happening but when when i update the same wh_id is updated for all the provided place_id

Answer (score 0):

The result you're seeing is exactly what the commented-out UPDATE statement says you want to do. In the update case you could replace the loop with a single update statement:

```
UPDATE POD_PLACE_WAREHOUSE_MAPPING_TB
  SET WH_ID = l_warehouse_list(l_warehouse_list.LAST).WH_ID
  WHERE PLACE_ID = p_PLACE_ID
```

The loop and the UPDATE statement above will produce the exact same results. In the loop case, you're updating all rows in POD_PLACE_WAREHOUSE_MAPPING_TB with each value from l_warehouse_list, one after the other. When the loop is complete all rows in POD_PLACE_WAREHOUSE_MAPPING_TB which have PLACE_ID = p_PLACE_ID will have their WH_ID column set to the WH_ID value from the l_warehouse_list element with the highest index.

I have no idea what other result you're expecting. I think you need to re-think what it is you're trying to do.

Best of luck.

Comment: yes exactly bob but i have a table in which i have multiple wh_id against eash place_id i need to update those wh_id with new wh_idis it possible or i need to delete and then update

Comment: I believe that to accomplish this you'll need to know both the PLACE_ID and the **old** WH_ID's, as well and the **new** WH_ID's. The UPDATE then becomes something like `UPDATE POD_PLACE_WAREHOUSE_MAPPING_TB SET WH_ID = new WH_ID WHERE PLACE_ID = p_PLACE_ID AND WH_ID = old WH_ID`. I hope that's clear enough. Share and enjoy.

Comment: yes i got ur point bhut how to implement this i need to select all the wh_id with a particular place_id and then initialize it to a collection and then provide new wh_ids ....how to i mplement this i have two table one in which i have all the wh_id and wh_nmames and another in which i have selected wh_id and place_id